# Differences in reflection between JDK 1.8 and JDK 16

Tags: java, reflection

The following statement was executed in both Oracle JDK1.8 and OpenJDK 16, but the different results returned. Founded during daily developping, the confusing issue is whether the difference are intended to be so or just an obscure bug? I've already done searching the similary questions but no expected ones was founded.

Examples,

```java
Field[] declaredFields = Field.class.getDeclaredFields();
// Field[12] with all private fields which are expected. (JDK 1.8)
// Empty field array. (JDK 16)
```

Through debug mode, the critical statements are located: line 293, 309 in jdk.internal.reflect.Reflections. Those methods left without javadoc.

```java
// line 293
return (Field[])filter(fields, fieldFilterMap.get(containingClass));

// line 309
if (filteredNames.contains(WILDCARD)) {
    return (Member[]) Array.newInstance(memberType, 0);
}
```

Comment: I think we need a specific example, an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

This is not an obscure bug but by intention.

Although the `filterFields()` method doesn't have a JavaDoc comment, the referenced `fieldFilterMap` field has (https://github.com/openjdk/jdk9/blob/master/jdk/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/reflect/Reflection.java#L42)

> Used to filter out fields and methods from certain classes from public        view, where they are sensitive or they may contain VM-internal objects.

As the referenced source is from Java 9 it was introduced intentionally and a comparison with the [Java 16 source](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk16/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/jdk/internal/reflect/Reflection.java#L52) shows that the number of excluded fields has increased since that time.

---

Is there a way around this restriction? I don't think so.

According to the issue tracker: [Improve filtering for classes with security sensitive fields](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8210496):

> The filters maintained by core reflection are a useful band aid to avoid leaking Field or Method objects to untrusted code. The filtering mechanism can be improved to filter out all fields **from highly security sensitive classes** such as Class, ClassLoader and some of the java.lang.reflect classes.

Every way around this restriction will probably be considered a security issue and will be closed in the next security update.

---

Unfortunately you don't state **why** you need this access. You need to change your code to not rely on access to these fields.

Please also note that most of the fields are accessible through getter methods.

Comment: Gracefully thanks!! For further, any possible ways to obtain those private fields?

Comment: No there isn't.  The point is that you shouldn't need to see those fields.

Comment: @JumoierezLeryn i've expanded my answer with a bit more information

Comment: Okay, the background is a simple coincidence. When skimming open-source projects, my colleague and I founded class named `DynamicEnumUtils`. The details contained in the blog below that might be the original: [niceideas](https://www.niceideas.ch/roller2/badtrash/entry/java_create_enum_instances_dynamically), but the code failed in JDK 16.  This weird and tricky code raised the curiosity, though it might be useless in biz.